# Real exchange rate of India and United State?

Tags: exchange-rates, price-level

According to [OECD](https://data.oecd.org/price/price-level-indices.htm) the price level of India is 29, and that of united states is 113, and nominal exchange rate is 64-1(INR-$). So what is the real exchange rate?

1. Is it $$RER = NER\times\frac{US_{PriceLevel}}{INR_{PriceLevel}}=273 \\ or \\RER = NER\times\frac{INR_{PriceLevel}}{US_{PriceLevel}}=16$$

I believe it should be the second one, because the price level in India is less than that in US so buying power of dollar should be less. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: This a trivial question you could easily solve by not omitting the units of measurement.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. I think price level should have units $(\$)^{-1}$ and $(inr)^-1$ and nominal exchange rate should be $(inr)/\$ $. Are these units correct?

Comment: Why do you think these are correct? Why do you think they are incorrect? The kind of questions you are posting to the site are [not a good match for a Stack Exchange](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions). These should be broad questions about concepts and theory, not "I did this, is it ok?"

Comment: I am extremely new to this. I don't have enough understanding of the subject to write questions in a way that is broad and general. I am not really asking this for a homework or an assignment but to improve my understanding. I will ask better questions in the future but I have to get stupid ones out the way first right. PS: Just second week since I started macroeconomics.

Comment: I sympathize but that is not what this SE is for.

Comment: @denesp do you know of a forum where I can get such doubts clarified.

Comment: Sorry, I don't. Talking to classmates is always a good option though!

Comment: I am out of luck there. Out of college and doing this as a self study thing.

Comment: All I can do is reiterate my sympathies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably one bundle of goods and services which costs about USD 113 in the United States would cost about USD 29 in India

so the bundle which costs about USD 113 in the United States would cost about INR 18546 in India at a market exchange rate of 64:1

suggesting a purchasing power parity of about INR 16.4 : USD 1

The [OECD calculations of PPPs](https://data.oecd.org/conversion/purchasing-power-parities-ppp.htm) suggest about 17:1 recently for India so this is the correct order of magnitude